# Generalization of approximate tangent spaces to subsets of arbitrary manifolds?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

I'm anything but an expert in Geometric Measure Theory, so please forgive me if I'm asking a trivial question.

Let $(M^n, g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A ⊂ M$ be a subset which is measurable w.r.t. the Hausdorff-$d$ measure $^d$ coming from the metric $g$. Embed $(M, g)$ isometrically into some $ℝ^N$. For $^d$-measurable subsets of $ℝ^N$ (like $A$) there exists the notion of approximate tangent spaces.

So suppose $A ⊂ M ⊂ ℝ^N$ has an approximate tangent space $T_x A$ at $x ∈ A$. Are the following statements true?

1. $T_x A$ is a subspace of $T_x M$.
2. $T_x A$ is independent of the isometric embedding.
3. (Assuming 2 is true), $T_x A$ is independent of the choice of $g$. (This requires that $^d$-measurability of $A$ is independent of the choice of $g$ which should be the case, unless I'm mistaken.)

Put differently, the question I'm asking is: In how far is the approximate tangent space of $A ⊂ M$ at $x$ an intrinsic concept, depending only on the structure of $A$ as a subset of $M$, and $M$ as a differentiable manifold? The main reason I'm asking is that I frequently need to switch between metrics (and thus isometric embeddings) and don't want to worry about approximate tangent spaces changing when I do that.

Answer (score 3):

We say that $x\in A$ is a density point if
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^d(A\cap B(x,r))}{\omega_d r^d}=1.
$$
It is well known that $\mathcal{H}^d$-almost all points of $A\subset M$ are density points.
At the density points we simply have that $T_xA=T_xM$. The density point is independent of a choice of a metric or an isometric embedding.

For an overview of basic results in geometric measure theory I would recommend

**F. Morgan,** *Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide*.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Piotr! I think I should have chosen less confusing variable names for the dimensions because judging from your statement $T_x A = T_x M$ I think you assumed $\mathop{dim} M = d$. In any case, this shouldn't matter too much. If $A$ is $d$-rectifiable, it it is contained in countably many $d$-dimensional manifolds $N_i$ up to a set of $^d$-measure zero, and then for $^d$-a.e. $x \in A$ the approximate tangent space $T_x A$ agrees with the tangent space of one of the $N_i$ and this is obviously an invariant notion and independent of any embedding. Thanks again!